# Scheme - How to find the median using user defined sort and average functions?

Tags: scheme, racket

I'm new to Scheme, and I've hit a wall. I have my sort and average functions, and I'm trying to change a median function I found on this site. However, no matter what I try, I keep getting errors where I have more than one expression in the median function, or when I try to use sort in the median function it's "undefined".

```
(define (sort1 L)
  (if (or (null? L) (<= (length L) 1)) L
    (let loop ((l null) (r null)
      (pivot (car L)) (rest (cdr L)))
        (if (null? rest)
          (append (append (sort1 l) (list pivot)) (sort1 r))
        (if (<= (car rest) pivot)
          (loop (append l (list (car rest))) r pivot (cdr rest))
          (loop l (append r (list (car rest))) pivot (cdr rest)))))))

(define (avg lst)
  (let loop ((count 0) (sum 0) (args lst))
    (if (not (null? args))
        (loop (add1 count) (+ sum (car args)) (cdr args))
        (/ sum count))))

(define (median L)
 (if (null? L) (error "The list is empty")
     (let loop ((L1 L) (L2 L))
       (cond ((null? (cdr L2)) (car L1))
             ((null? (cddr L2)) (list (car L1) (cadr L1)))
             (else (loop (cdr L1) (cddr L2)))))))
```

I'm trying to edit the median function to first sort the list, and if there are an even number of elements, I need to take the average of the list, and use the element closest to the average.

Any help would be appreciated, thank you in advance.

Comment: I see many basic parenthesis errors. For example in the definition of `median`, there are two parens before the first `let`, which you probably didn't intend, and there are also two parens after `(sort1 lst)`, which means that that `let` is missing a body. Then you're also missing a paren before the `let loop`. Fix those first, then ask your real question. Remember that parentheses normally mean function application.

Comment: I restored them to their original code, and it should all be fixed because the function works now - but I need it to sort list input, and should the list contain an even number of elements, to return the element (of the two middle elements) that's closest to the average.

Comment: If you want to do one thing, then do another, that's function composition. So you want to sort the list, then apply this median function? Rename the median function to `median/sorted`, and define the real `median` function as a composition of `sort1` and `median/sorted`.

Comment: Is there a way I can call the sorted function within the median function, and then use the sorted list instead of the inputted-possibly-unsorted list? I was able to edit the median function to return the correct element should the list contain an even number of elements, but I'm still having trouble sorting it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Like I said in a comment, what you want isn't a `let`, it's function composition.

Your current median function is this:

```
(define (median L)
  (if (null? L)
      (error "The list is empty")
      (let loop ((L1 L) (L2 L))
        (cond ((null? (cdr L2)) (car L1))
              ((null? (cddr L2)) (list (car L1) (cadr L1)))
              (else (loop (cdr L1) (cddr L2)))))))
```

But as Oscar Lopez pointed out, this doesn't properly compute the median. However, it does some of the work, so keep it. Rename it to `median-helper` or something.

```
(define (median-helper L)
  (if (null? L)
      (error "The list is empty")
      (let loop ((L1 L) (L2 L))
        (cond ((null? (cdr L2)) (car L1))
              ((null? (cddr L2)) (list (car L1) (cadr L1)))
              (else (loop (cdr L1) (cddr L2)))))))
```

Then you can use function composition to define the "real" median function:

```
(define (median lst)
   (median-helper (sort1 lst)))
```

This returns the middle element for odd-length lists, and the middle-two elements for even length lists. If this is want you wanted, great. If not, then you can fix `median-helper` by returning the average in the second case of the `cond`. So instead of `(list (car L1) (cadr L1))` there, you would have `(avg (list (car L1) (cadr L1)))`.

```
;; median-helper : (Listof Number) -> Number
(define (median-helper L)
  (if (null? L)
      (error "The list is empty")
      (let loop ((L1 L) (L2 L))
        (cond ((null? (cdr L2)) (car L1))
              ((null? (cddr L2)) (avg (list (car L1) (cadr L1))))
              (else (loop (cdr L1) (cddr L2)))))))

;; median : (Listof Number) -> Number
(define (median lst)
   (median-helper (sort1 lst)))
```

Comment: ... I can't believe I didn't get that from your comment, those two lines of code for median were all I needed. Thank you!

Comment: Yep, was doing some finishing touches in case I ran into any other problems. Thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

I think you're misunderstanding the definition of a [median](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Median). A very simple (if not particularly efficient) implementation follows:

```
(define (my-sort L)
  (sort L <))

(define (average x y)
  (exact->inexact (/ (+ x y) 2)))

(define (median L)
  (if (null? L)
      (error "The list is empty")
      (let* ((n (length L))
             (sorted (my-sort L))
             (half (quotient n 2)))
        (if (odd? n)
            (list-ref sorted half)
            (average (list-ref sorted half)
                     (list-ref sorted (sub1 half)))))))
```

It works as defined:

```
(median '())
=> The list is empty
(median '(3 2 1 5 4))
=> 3
(median '(6 4 3 1 2 5))
=> 3.5
```

Comment: I know what the definition of median is, but for this particular problem, we were also supposed to implement a mean function, and to do so we are asked to use the mean to determine what to return for the median should the number of elements in the list be even. 
Edit: Also I figured that bit out, at this point I'm just trying to get the list sorted.

Comment: @WolvenOmega I named `average` what you call `mean`, but it's way simpler than you think, you only have to compute the mean of the two middle elements in a sorted list with an even number of elements